# How to convert svg+xml base64 to UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, svgkit

I simply have string like this:

`"data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"`

How do I convert it into UIImage using [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) cocoapod library?

For now I simply use:

```
var image: UIImage? {
    guard let imageEncodedString = imageEncodedString else {
        return nil
    }
    return SVGKImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: imageEncodedString))?.uiImage //crash here inside init
}
```

Comment: Thank you for voting down, but if you think it is easy, then please answer first before voting down;)

Comment: Do you need to remove `data:image/svg+xml;base64,` first?

Comment: Yes, of course, but how to do it without `replace:with`?

Comment: Search for "," and remove everything before? If I don't know what are the possible values or what they look like, for the "beginning" invalid part, it's hard to tell...

Answer (score 1):

The beginning of the string is not base64, that's why it's failing. You need to remove first `data:image/svg+xml;base64,`.

You have a [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

It should be like that:

```
data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>
```

You currently have:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,theBase64Image
```

Now, you can either remove always `data:image/svg+xml;base64,` from your string:

```
let dataURI = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,theBase64Image"
let base64String = dataURI.replacingOccurrences(of: "data:image/svg+xml;base64,", with: "")
```

You can also check before hand if `hasPrefix()` to ensure that it has the expected dataURI. You could also use a Regex, `NSScanner`, etc. to do so.

But since you expect SVG in base64, `hasPrefix()` and `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` should be enough.

Comment: I would acceot that answer, but have you read comment under question?;) How to do this without replacing beginning string?

Comment: Use a library that accept it. And I guess it will itself do the replace under the hood. You have a method that accepts Base64 for the init. Not DataURI + Base64. So what do you expect?